# Let Entity Framework (code first) ignore an indexed property

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, indexed-properties

In an entity I have following declaration:

```
Default Property Item(key As String) As String
```

Because Entity Framework doesn't like indexed properties I've tried to ignore it:

```
Public Class EntityMap
    Inherits EntityTypeConfiguration(Of EntityMap)
    Public Sub New()
        ' Me.Ignore(Function(x) x.Item()) --- Missing index parameter, compiler error
        ' Me.Ignore(Function(x) x.Item(String.Empty)) --- Gives runtime error
    End Sub
End Class
```

I've also tried to remove all discovery conventions from modelBuilder so all property relations explicitely must be set:

```
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(Of AssociationInverseDiscoveryConvention)()
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(Of ComplexTypeDiscoveryConvention)()
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(Of IdKeyDiscoveryConvention)()
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(Of NavigationPropertyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention)()
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(Of PrimaryKeyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention)()
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(Of TypeNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention)()
```

When the linq query to fetch entities is executed the exception "Indexed properties are not supported" is thrown.

Anyone having any idea how to let Entity Framework ignore the indexed property? The property must be public to other entities.

Thanks in advance!