# Entity Framework Code First - Indexed properties are not supported

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

Using indexers on a poco with entity framework code first throws the error "Indexed properties are not supported." when saving the context.

Is there a way to use indexers on pocos with entity framework code first? I tried applying the [NotMapped] attribute to the indexer declaration but it did not help.

Comment: It seems [like limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199442/let-entity-framework-code-first-ignore-an-indexed-property) of EF fluent mapping.

Comment: Indeed, I have filed a [report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/754309/entity-framework-code-first-cannot-ignore-custom-class-indexers-in-entitytypeconfiguration) on Microsoft connect site for this issue..

Answer (score 0):

Try using WriteEDMX to see whether the EDMX is referencing those properties - I suspect it isn't and that the limitation is with the core EF runtime not Code First (Code First is finished by the time you create your first DbContext).